# Tweedie cumulative distribution function

Tags: r, cumulative-distribution-function

I am trying to calculate the cdf of a Tweedie distribution. The R function `ptweedie` gives me some weird results and I do not understand why.
Here some code in R

```
y <- 153638
mean <- 140713.1
disp <- 824.8392

ptweedie(q = y, xi = 1, mu = mean, phi = disp)
```

It's very weird that I get 1 as a result. the `y` value is not that high considering the value of the `mean`. So I try this:

```
sim <- rtweedie(100000, xi = 1, mu = mean, phi = disp)

hist(sim)
abline(v = y, col = "red")

sum(sim <= y) / 100000
```

Why these two values are not similar as in this case?

```
y <- 1.96
sim <- rnorm(100000)

hist(sim)
abline(v = y, col = "red")

pnorm(q = y)

sum(sim <= y) / 100000
```

What is it wrong here?
Thank you

Comment: Your question seems to be about R code, which is off topic here (although I tried to run your code and got errors; mgcv has rTweedie not rtweedie and it does not have a xi option; what package did you use?)

However, if you are asking a statistics question you could reword your question to show that.